# Java wait and notify makes deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run two threads one after the other, without using sleep() or Locks, but a deadlock happens! What's wrong with my code? I used wait() and notifyAll() and an Object object.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PrintChar a = new PrintChar('a');
        PrintChar b = new PrintChar('b');
        Thread ta = new Thread(a);
        Thread tb = new Thread(b);
        ta.start();
        tb.start();
    }
}

class PrintChar implements Runnable {
    final Object o = new Object();
    char ch;
    public PrintChar(char a) {
        ch = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            synchronized (o) {
                System.out.print(ch);
                try {
                    o.wait();
                    o.notifyAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want sequential execution, why are you using threads?

Comment: Never mind  EJP! Just practicing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running your code, and looking at it, I've found that each thread you generated was generating and synchronizing to its own object, therefore preventing them from notifying each other. I've also found that you wait before notify, so you do not ever get to invoke `o.notifyAll()`, as `o.wait()` stops it first.

Change `final Object o = new Object()` to `static final Object o = new Object()`, and switch the places of `o.wait()` and `o.notifyAll()`

Answer (score -1):

I think the `synchronized` block is causing the *deadlock*. Cos it won't let the other thread start until current one finished. You are using `wait()` method to make the current thread wait. Ok, it will wait but since it is in `synchronized` block, it will be in the current thread forever never let any other thread to came into existence because of `synchronized`.

One thing you can do to make the other thread work is using `Thread.stop`. Try calling `stop method` in current thread's reference. But I am not sure whether it will let the current thread to start again.

Comment: but definitely this will start other thread as per your question without using **sleep()** :)

Comment: This is wrong, since half the function of `Object.wait()` is to atomically release the lock held on it. It is actually required to be called from within a `synchronized` block on the object in question.